# rails tests confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, bdd

I have been trying to determine a good way to test rails apps, covering all relevant aspects... since I have no experience writing tests at all I have been looking at railscasts.com which seems like a pretty good resource to learn basic stuff for rails. but for tests I have found several episodes, some using rails unit test classes, others use Cucumber, RSPEC, ZenTest, Autotests, Webrat, Selenium, etc.

So Im now just not sure if Im supposed to pick one of these or a combination. are some of these now old and obsolete?? are they mutually exclusive?... basically I want to learn testing for rails and would like to hear opinions on how to properly and sufficiently test rails apps and what framework to use for the different types of tests

please help, thanks in advance

ps. if someone can provide a good resource for learning the difference between unit tests, integration tests and so on I'd appreciate it.... I know I didnt do TDD or BDD cause my app is pretty much done now, and all seems to be working just fine. but I still would like to add tests for learning purposes and future developments.

Answer (score 2):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: That's a good resource but it doesnt provide any info on any of the frameworks I listed. Which is what created my confusion in the first place

Comment: but my question is more targeted at figuring out these frameworks.. What is the difference between webrat and rspec?? what should I use???

does it make sense using both??... I want to know what most developers do

Comment: Your question is expressed too broadly. Just pick one and try it out.

Comment: If you dont know dont answer man.... its not about picking one.. which one!?.. also some of these are supposed to work together... It makes no sense picking autotest INSTEAD of Webrat...